# How to clear what has been previously declared with \AtEndDocument?

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes

I am using a class file that uses `\AtEndDocument` to include a table of contents at the end of the document. However, I would like to override the original `\AtEndDocument` and force the document not to have a TOC at all *without* having to change the document class. How can I achieve that?

The `.cls` file without the :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{docclass}[2009/07/02 Whitepaper Style]
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{landscape}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{openright}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{leqno}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions
%%
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany,chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[english]{varioref}
\RequirePackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{datetime}
\RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{ae}
\RequirePackage{bbding}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage[
    pdftex,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    menucolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    breaklinks=false,
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    pdfstartview=FitH
    ]{hyperref}

%% more commands

\fontfamily{cmss}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{%
    pdftitle={\HREFpdftitle},
    pdfauthor={\HREFpdfauthor},
    pdfsubject={\HREFpdfsubject},
    pdfkeywords={\HREFpdfkeywords},
    pdfcreator={\HREFpdfcreator}
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \newpage\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{TOC}\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
```

The document:

```
\documentclass{docclass}
\begin{document}
\section*{Section 1}
foo bar baz
\section*{Section 2}
lorem ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

**Note:** I have tried simply including `\AtEndDocument{}` in the document, but this doesn't yield the expected result.

Comment: You can use loops to avoid copious use of estate by similar calls to the same command. See the documentation of *catoptions* package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\global\let\@enddocumenthook\@empty
\makeatother
```

will clear the macro that saves the tokens added by `\AtEndDocument`

```
\AtEndDocument{}
```

doesn't work as you can have many calls to this command each *adds* the declarations to the existing hook (so that adds nothing but leaves the existing declarations in place)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this swift response. Works like a charm. I'm going to accept as soon as I can.

Comment: David, @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Note that this will clear *all* code added to the hook previously, which might break the functionality of packages will add their own code there.

Comment: @MartinScharrer yes that was the requested behaviour:-) If you know exactly what tokens are in the hook it is of course possible to do rather more delicate surgery to remove the tokens or redefine them

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general solution. Since there might be unscannable tokens in `\@enddocumenthook`, I first check for scannability before attempting to filter test tokens from the token list `\@enddocumenthook`. The solution is not trivial.

You can release `\@enddocumenthook` at (1) and do `\show\y` to see that the example at the end behaves as required.

If the test token isn't unique in `\@enddocumenthook`, a wrong match can occur. For this reason, I have introduced a new command `\NewAtEndDocument`, which is to be used in place of `\AtEndDocument` if tokens will be filtered from `\@enddocumenthook`.

Tokens have to be filtered out in the same lot that they have been included in `\@enddocumenthook`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\newletcs\ltsrelax\relax
\robust@def\NewAtEndDocument#1{%
  \g@addto@macro\@enddocumenthook{\ltsrelax#1\ltsrelax}%
}
\robust@def\FilterAtEndDocumentHook{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar\m@ne
  \edef\reserved@a##1{%
    \def##1\detokenize{macro}:->####1\ltsrelax{%
      \def\string\reserved@a{####1}%
    }%
    \edef##1{##1\meaning\@enddocumenthook\ltsrelax}%
  }%
  \reserved@a\reserved@a
  \makeatletter\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\reserved@a}\relax
  \ifx\@enddocumenthook\reserved@a\else
    \endgroup
    \@latex@error{\noexpand\@enddocumenthook is no longer scannable}\@ehd
  \fi
  \cpt@testst\Filt@rAtEndDocumentHook
}
\robust@def\Filt@rAtEndDocumentHook#1{%
  \def\filter@remove##1{%
    \xifinsetFT{##1}{\cptoxdetok\@enddocumenthook}{}{%
      \def\reserved@a####1##1####2\filter@nil{%
        \def\@enddocumenthook{####1####2}%
        \ifboolFT{cpt@st}{}{\filter@remove{##1}}%
      }%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\detokenize\expandafter
        {\@enddocumenthook}\filter@nil
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\filter@remove\expandafter{\detokenize{\ltsrelax#1\ltsrelax}}%
  \cptscantokens\@enddocumenthook
  \postgroupdef\@enddocumenthook\endgroup
}

% Examples:
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\x#1{#1}}
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\y#1{#1}}
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\x#1{#1}}
% The starred variant of \FilterAtEndDocumentHook will remove all occurrences of
% the test token ('\def\x#1{#1}' in the following example). The non-starred form
% will remove only one occurrence.
\FilterAtEndDocumentHook*{\def\x#1{#1}}
% \@enddocumenthook % (1)

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Here is a solution that doesn't require rescanning of `\@enddocumenthook`. This is to be preferred.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter

\let\do@enddoc\@firstofone
\def\added@enddocumenthook{}
\grightaddtocs\@enddocumenthook{\added@enddocumenthook}
\robust@def\NewAtEndDocument#1{%
  \cptexpandarg{\grightaddtocs\added@enddocumenthook}%
    {\noexpand\do@enddoc{\cpttrimspace{#1}}}%
}
\robust@def*\FilterAtEndDocumentHook{%
  \begingroup
  \cpt@testopt\Filt@rAtEndDocumentHook{1}%
}
\robust@def\Filt@rAtEndDocumentHook[#1]#2{%
  \edef\reserved@b{\cpttrimspace{#2}}%
  \@tempcnta\z@
  \def\do@enddoc##1{%
    \toks@{\edef\added@enddocumenthook
      {\expandcsonce\added@enddocumenthook\unexpanded{\do@enddoc{##1}}}}%
    \edef\reserved@a{\unexpanded{##1}}%
    \ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b
      \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
      \ifnum\@tempcnta>\@iden{#1}\relax
        \the\toks@
      \fi
    \else
      \the\toks@
    \fi
  }%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\added@enddocumenthook\expandafter
    {\expandafter}\added@enddocumenthook
  \postgroupdef\added@enddocumenthook\endgroup
}

% Examples:
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\x#1{#1}}
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\y#1{#1}}
\NewAtEndDocument{\def\x#1{#1}}
% Use the optional argument of \FilterAtEndDocumentHook to specify the number of
% occurrences of the test token to be removed (2 in the following example).
\FilterAtEndDocumentHook[2]{\def\x#1{#1}}
% \@enddocumenthook % (1)
% \show\y

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```